# Counting how many times a value is

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to construct a query in MSSQL that counts how many times some one is late, so for example there could be 4 records in a day for one person E.g arriving, Dinner, Dinner, Leaving.

as a quick example assuming the "arriving" time is  9:15am and the expected arrival time is 9am, this would count as being late, however if i need to check say a weeks worth of data so 5 days, ideally there would be 20 records and every 4th record would be the one we need to count. however the data is not that reliable as it's all down to the user of the system swiping there card.

What would be the best way of doing this?

```
SELECT   COUNT(EventTM) AS Time
            FROM        
                    CHINA_VISION_DorEvents
            WHERE    
                            (CardCode = '007b8a5a') 
               AND (DorCtrls_Ref = '16') 
               AND (EventTM >= DATEADD(hour, 0, DATEADD(day, 0, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS date) AS datetime))))
               And convert(Time,EventTM) < '08:08:00'
```

This query doesn't really work in any aspect of what i have described, but basically this can tell me if they were early for one specific day

and i need to know if they were early/late for each day in the date range.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do GROUP BY "date-without-time-part", and just COUNT(*).

Comment: Why are you doing a convert in count?

Comment: @artm no reason, it was there from earlier testing

Comment: Move the condition into a CASE and then COUNT(*) and COUNT(CASE).

Comment: Please put some sample data

Comment: Do you differentiate the events for which time is logged? How do you differentiate the time logged is for which event?

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this.

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
  (
     id             INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
     name           VARCHAR(50),
     Action         VARCHAR(50),
     Date_of_action DATETIME
  )

INSERT INTO @MyTable
VALUES      ('Aaa',
             'Arriving',
             '1-Jan-2015 9:00:00 AM'),
            ('Aaa',
             'Dinner',
             '1-Jan-2015 11:00:00 AM'),
            ('Aaa',
             'Dinner',
             '1-Jan-2015 2:00:00 PM'),
            ('Aaa',
             'Leaving',
             '1-Jan-2015 6:00:00 PM'),
            ('Aaa',
             'Arriving',
             '2-Jan-2015 9:15:00 AM'),
            ('Aaa',
             'Dinner',
             '2-Jan-2015 11:00:00 AM'),
            ('Aaa',
             'Dinner',
             '2-Jan-2015 2:00:00 PM'),
            ('Aaa',
             'Leaving',
             '2-Jan-2015 6:00:00 PM'),
            ('Aaa',
             'Arriving',
             '3-Jan-2015 9:00:00 AM'),
            ('Aaa',
             'Dinner',
             '3-Jan-2015 11:00:00 AM'),
            ('Aaa',
             'Dinner',
             '3-Jan-2015 2:00:00 PM'),
            ('Aaa',
             'Leaving',
             '3-Jan-2015 6:00:00 PM'),
            ('Aaa',
             'Arriving',
             '4-Jan-2015 9:00:00 AM'),
            ('Aaa',
             'Dinner',
             '4-Jan-2015 11:00:00 AM'),
            ('Aaa',
             'Dinner',
             '4-Jan-2015 2:00:00 PM'),
            ('Aaa',
             'Leaving',
             '4-Jan-2015 6:00:00 PM'),
            ('Aaa',
             'Arriving',
             '5-Jan-2015 9:00:00 AM'),
            ('Aaa',
             'Dinner',
             '5-Jan-2015 11:00:00 AM'),
            ('Aaa',
             'Dinner',
             '5-Jan-2015 2:00:00 PM'),
            ('Aaa',
             'Leaving',
             '5-Jan-2015 6:00:00 PM'),
            ('Baa',
             'Arriving',
             '1-Jan-2015 9:00:00 AM'),
            ('Baa',
             'Dinner',
             '1-Jan-2015 11:00:00 AM'),
            ('Baa',
             'Dinner',
             '1-Jan-2015 2:00:00 PM'),
            ('Baa',
             'Leaving',
             '1-Jan-2015 6:00:00 PM'),
            ('Baa',
             'Arriving',
             '2-Jan-2015 9:00:00 AM'),
            ('Baa',
             'Dinner',
             '2-Jan-2015 11:00:00 AM'),
            ('Baa',
             'Dinner',
             '2-Jan-2015 2:00:00 PM'),
            ('Baa',
             'Leaving',
             '2-Jan-2015 6:00:00 PM'),
            ('Baa',
             'Arriving',
             '3-Jan-2015 9:00:00 AM'),
            ('Baa',
             'Dinner',
             '3-Jan-2015 11:00:00 AM'),
            ('Baa',
             'Dinner',
             '3-Jan-2015 2:00:00 PM'),
            ('Baa',
             'Leaving',
             '3-Jan-2015 6:00:00 PM'),
            ('Baa',
             'Arriving',
             '4-Jan-2015 9:00:00 AM'),
            ('Baa',
             'Dinner',
             '4-Jan-2015 11:00:00 AM'),
            ('Baa',
             'Dinner',
             '4-Jan-2015 2:00:00 PM'),
            ('Baa',
             'Leaving',
             '4-Jan-2015 6:00:00 PM'),
            ('Baa',
             'Arriving',
             '5-Jan-2015 9:00:00 AM'),
            ('Baa',
             'Dinner',
             '5-Jan-2015 11:00:00 AM'),
            ('Baa',
             'Dinner',
             '5-Jan-2015 2:00:00 PM'),
            ('Baa',
             'Leaving',
             '5-Jan-2015 6:00:00 PM')

SELECT t.name as LateCommersList,t.Date_of_action
FROM   (SELECT Name,
               date_of_Action,
               ROW_NUMBER()
                 OVER (
                   partition BY CONVERT(DATE, date_of_action)
                   ORDER BY name, date_of_Action) rn
        FROM   @MyTable)t
WHERE  rn = 1
       AND CONVERT(TIME(7), Date_of_action) > '9:00:00.0000000'
```